# java security exception on OS X

Tags: java, macos, ssl-certificate, java-security

I am getting Java security issues on a Macbook Pro running El Capitan: `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException`.

This occurs for building my projects (ivy chokes on `https://repo1.maven.org`) as well as running my code (can't reach `https://s3.amazonaws.com`, etc.)

I have read several similar questions and answers talking to how to add certificates to the java keystore.  I have indeed used that to successfully add `repo1.maven.org` to the keystore for example.  But it seems to me something is not quite correct to start with.  Why is it that this is the only host where this is happening?  I compile, install and run Java programs on many different hosts, accessing the https/SSL layer all over the place, and thus far I've never had to add certificates by hand for this to work!

So the question is, what is special about that host?  Is there some system setting that tell Java to be extra picky?  I compared the the `cacerts` file between that Macbook and other machines where there are no certificate issues, and the certificates are identical.

I use the Oracle/Sun `jdk1.8.0_102` on all machines, and I compare the cacerts by using the ouput of:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts > cacerts.txt
```

on the various machines.  They all match.  Yet Java on the Macbook is throwing these `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed` all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  Turns out that Macbook has BlueCoat unified agent installed. It is known to interfere with SSL certificates.

I temporarily disabled it and that fixed all the HTTPS issues reported above.  I will work with IT to figure out a more proper, long-term solution.